# Case insensitive regex with Postgres and JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I currently use this code with JOOQ:

```
Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
if( isNotBlank(email) ){
  condition = condition.and(APP_USER.EMAIL.likeRegex(email));
}
```

That ends up issuing Postgres specific SQL that does the regex match in the DB:

```
app_user.email ~ '{email regex}'
```

Is it possible to get JOOQ to issue the [case insensitive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) version: `app_user.email ~* '{email regex}'`?

---

My current workaround is to use this code:

```
if( isNotBlank(email) ){
  condition = condition.and(
    APP_USER.EMAIL.lower().likeRegex(email.toLowerCase()) );
}
```

Comment: You might have to use a raw native query here.  The `likeRegex()` method may only accept the pattern.  This would make sense because it should be exposed as being DB independent.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Good idea - do you know if that can be done with JOOQ at the condition level?  I don't want to turn this thing into a complete native query because it would get quite complex (better to stick with the lowercase workaround I think).

Comment: Here's the thing: If JOOQ is sitting on top of JDBC, then there may not be a way to do this, because making a regex case insensitive in Postgres is a DB specific thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Hold my beer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If ever the jOOQ API is missing vendor-specific functionality, the answer is ["plain SQL"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). In your case, simply write this:

#### PostgreSQL-specific solution

```
Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
if( isNotBlank(email) ){
  condition = condition.and("{0} ~* {1}", APP_USER.EMAIL, DSL.val(email));
}
```

The method [`Condition.and(String, QueryPart...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html#and-java.lang.String-org.jooq.QueryPart...-) is just convenience for creating an explicit plain SQL `Condition` through [`DSL.condition(String, QueryPart...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-java.lang.String-org.jooq.QueryPart...-):

```
Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
if( isNotBlank(email) ){
  condition = condition.and(DSL.condition("{0} ~* {1}", APP_USER.EMAIL, DSL.val(email)));
}
```

#### Vendor-agnostic solution

If you want to be vendor-agnostic, you'd have to wrap the above code in your own utility and resort to using a [`CustomCondition`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/CustomCondition.html)

```
public static Condition caseInsensitiveLikeRegex(Field<String> field, String regex) {
    return new CustomCondition() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Context<?> ctx) {
            if (ctx.family() == POSTGRES)
                ctx.visit(DSL.condition("{0} ~* {1}", field, DSL.val(regex));
            else
                ctx.visit(field.lower().likeRegex(regex.toLowerCase()));
        }
    }
}
```

The `regex.toLowerCase()` call is not 100% correct, of course, as it lower cases both the regex content, as well as the escaped patterns, such as `\B` for backslash, but you get the idea.

Comment: Went with the first option - works great.  +1 for "hold my beer".

Comment: The answer Devriprasad posted today made me think about SQL-injection issues.  Does `DSL.condition()` have similar concerns regarding string concatenation related SQL-injection, or is it using proper JDBC binding parameters?

Comment: Oof - https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Condition.html#and(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @Shorn: Why not ask a question with details? I can answer with details. It's not really related to this question and answer here... As a teaser, Devriprasad's answer doesn't have a SQLi vulnerability. Plain SQL templating obviously is vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
condition=condition.and(APP_USER.EMAIL.likeIgnoreCase("%"+email+"%"));
```